# AWS FileSystemCredentials is not a constructor

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to load a JSON config file to protect my AWS keys

```
a.FileSystemCredentials is not a constructor
at constructor.loadFromPath(aws - sdk.min.js: 46)
```

This error is preventing me from using `AWS.config.loadFromPath('../../s3.config.json');`

It works fine when i use the unprotected `AWS.config.update([json]);` where `json` is the actual jsonData

app.js:

```
AWS.config.loadFromPath('../../s3.config.json');
var hub = new AWS.S3({ params: {Bucket: 'mybucket'} });
```

s3.config.json

{
    "accessKeyId": "keyid",
    "secretAccessKey": "secretkey",
    "region": "us-east-1"
}

Comment: Did you solve the issue? Because I have the same thing happening to me right now. Would appreciate some directions since it was 3 month for you :-)

Comment: Thank you for the workaround tip to use AWS.config.update!

Answer (score 6):

I have the same issue. You are probably loading the aws js sdk for browser.

As you can see: https://sdk.amazonaws.com/builder/js/, `AWS.FileSystemCredentials` is not included, that is why `FileSystemCredentials` is not a constructor (to be more specific it is undefined). It looks like you can only use `AWS.config.loadFromPath` on server side (with something like node.js).

Comment: `It looks like you can only use AWS.config.loadFromPath on server side (with something like node.js).` -- doing the same ...not helping

Answer (score 2):

Loading credentials from a JSON document is not supported in browser scripts.You have to create an identity pool and give permission for the required access

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});

AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({IdentityPoolId: 'ur pool id'});
```